# who edited part of the document in SharePoint online

Tags: version-history, auditing, collaboration

There are 5 persons editing the same Word document. I want to see who edited one part of it. Is that possible in SharePoint online?

Answer (score 2):

Well Sharepoint will record Version History (if enabled in the Document Library Settings).

However, it seems like you need to use **Track Changes** in the Word settings.  This allows multiple users to work on a file e.g. a report, Word records 'who did what'.  You'll need to familiarise yourself with the settings to see how it behaves.

[image: Track Changes in Word]

However, if you really need something in Sharepoint to track this, then Sharepoint will only record data from the 'properties' e.g. Created, Modified Date, plus Version History - the latter will record when fields were changed.

You can create custom fields to track certain information, you might be able to configure something whereby a document editor can only see the file **assigned to** them.  Sharepoint will track changes made to the 'Assigned To' people field, therefore you would gain some visibility on the person responsible for created that version of the document.

You may also wish to investigate using an 'Approval Workflow' for document management.

**Further reading**

Just found this one - [very relevant](https://sharepointmaven.com/co-authoring-documents-in-sharepoint/).

Comment: Thing is, for me in word online, there's no Track Changes option. It's simply not there and I can't find any word setting to turn it on.

Comment: Hi Catalin - I found this on the MS website [link](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/can-i-use-track-changes-in-word-online-9016b7f8-b864-458f-ba45-183049f90bd8) which says "You can’t see tracked changes in Word Online but they’re still there. When you open a document in Word Online that has tracked changes, they’re preserved and any changes you make will also be tracked. You just won’t see them until you open the document in the Word desktop application." Have a read, I think it will help you.

Comment: One other thing the post mentions with regards to Track Changes showing.  If it opens the file in the browser it won't show Track Changes.  If that happens you'll need to adjust the Doc Library settings default - to make it open in Word instead of the browser.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the auditing feature of SharePoint online to achieve this. For more information, please checkout the following link:

[How to enable SharePoint Online auditing](http://blog.ciaops.com/2015/04/enabling-sharepoint-online-auditing.html)

[View audit log reports](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/view-audit-log-reports-b37c5869-1b47-4a82-a30d-ea20070fe527)

Addittionally, you may check the third party online auditing [solution](https://www.lepide.com/lepideauditor/sharepoint-online-auditing.html) to track who has done what.